# How can I ensure that my Python regular expression outputs a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, json

I'm using Beej's Python Flickr API to ask Flickr for JSON. The unparsed string Flickr returns looks like this:

```
jsonFlickrApi({'photos': 'example'})
```

I want to access the returned data as a dictionary, so I have:

```
photos = "jsonFlickrApi({'photos': 'test'})"

# to match {'photos': 'example'}
response_parser = re.compile(r'jsonFlickrApi\((.*?)\)$')
parsed_photos = response_parser.findall(photos)
```

However, parsed_photos is a list, not a dictionary (according to type(parsed_photos). It outputs like:

```
["{'photos': 'test'}"]
```

How can I ensure that my parsed data ends up as a dictionary type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a JSON parser to convert the string representation to actual Python data structure. Take a look at the documentation of the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module in the standard library for some examples.

In other words you'd have to add the following line at the end of your code

```
photos = json.loads(parsed_photos[0])
```

PS. In theory you could also use `eval` to achieve the same effect, as JSON is (almost) compatible with Python literals, but doing that would open a huge security hole. Just to let you know.

Comment: Not quite true - you cannot use an eval, as JSON is not compatible with Python literals. Examples: Python uses `None`; JSON uses `null`. Python uses `True`/`False`; JSON uses `true`/`false`

Comment: @Smashery: It's not a syntactical difference, you just have to define locals for null/true/false and everything will be fine. Not that it's something I'd recommend, just use the libraries.

Comment: I've used your first suggestion to get a dictionary - thanks very much! Can you please explain what the [0] in parsed_photos[0] represents?

Comment: @bfox: findAll returns an array of all matches for a given regular expression, [0] takes only the first element.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 2.6, you can just use the JSON module to parse JSON stuff.

```
import json
json.loads(dictString)
```

If you're using an earlier version of Python, you can download the [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/) module and use that.

Example:

```
>>> json.loads('{"hello" : 4}')
{u'hello': 4}
```