# Format Open Library JSON dump into parseable Python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, json

I was hoping someone has had some experience with Open Library and trying to parse their downloadable JSON dumps. I would like to be able to parse the JSON and turn it into CSV, but am having an issue getting this JSON into a clean format.

The issue is it looks like this "JSON" is a mix of some tab delimited data at the beginning then some structured JSON.

Are there any utilities that can clean this type of data up or I am going to have to write some squirrelly find & replace script?

Here is an example of the dump (2 items):

```
/type/author    /authors/OL1000057A 2   2008-08-20T17:57:09.66187   {"name": "Kha\u0304lid Muh\u0323ammad \u02bbAli\u0304 al-H\u0323a\u0304jj", "personal_name": "Kha\u0304lid Muh\u0323ammad \u02bbAli\u0304 al-H\u0323a\u0304jj", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:09.66187"}, "key": "/authors/OL1000057A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}

/type/author    /authors/OL100029A  2   2008-09-08T16:19:17.29978   {"name": "K. Hardono", "personal_name": "K. Hardono", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-09-08T16:19:17.29978"}, "key": "/authors/OL100029A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
```

I need to  wrap the JSON sets in a list [ ] and comma separate for my parse to run correctly.

Thanks for the code cleanup BTW.

Comment: What you've got there is CSV data, where one of the fields is JSON ... so the obvious approach is to open it as CSV, extract the JSON field, and then process that.

Comment: Ugh thats what I was not looking forward to but it does seem like the only viable option. What is this '\u0304' in the JSON, some special characters or encoding?

Comment: `\u0304` represents [a code point](http://codepoints.net/U+0304) in Unicode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I ensure that my Python regular expression outputs a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964621/how-can-i-ensure-that-my-python-regular-expression-outputs-a-dictionary)

Comment: Posting here for future users, I wrote a ruby gem that will parse the csv to a json - this json file can be used for easy parsing: https://github.com/thearjunmdas/openlibrary-dump-parser

Answer (score 0):

you can use a php parser for this purpose.
it gives all of data as packets.

use OPDumpReader for parsing OpenLibrary Dumps

https://github.com/manindersingh030/OLDumpReader

> $reader = new OLReader($dumpLocation);
>
> var_dump($reader->getNextPacket());